# App stops working when offline after installing cordova.network-information plugin (even when app does nothing)

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I needed to check connectivity for my phonegap android application so I downloaded the latest version of the cordova network information plug in from here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md.

The sample code below actually works as intended if there is some network connectivity, but as soon as the phone goes offline the app just alerts "unfortunately,  has stopped. The crazy thing is this happens even for the simple hello world app (the one that only check to see if the device is ready). Basically the app runs fine before adding the plugin. But after you run cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information and rebuild, it gives the same alert when the phone is offline. And this is without changing any code.

```
function checkConnection() {
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
var states = {};
states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]); 
}
checkConnection();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nedd more information like which version of phonegap you are using. 
Meanwhile if your requirement is to check only for offline and online case you can simply use:

```
function checkConnection() { if(navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE){
//no connection
}else{
//You are connected.
}
```

I assume you have included android version of cordova.js in you html page.

Comment: i'm using the latest version, and downloading the plugin from here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md. The problem is the app literally doesn't even open if there is no network connection. So if I open a new directory, do:                                         cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova platform add android
cordova build. Then if I add the plugin and run the app on my android after disconnecting from the network, the app just says unfortuantely it has stopped. And this app doesn't even use the plugin.

Comment: are you able to see logcat?? please see if there is any error.

Comment: Thanks for the help i'll look into that, but for now the version at this link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html works fine. Looks like there is probably an error with the latest version.